# How to break a long mapping line into several short lines in vimrc mapping

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I have a very long vimrc mapping to deal with for example

```
nnoremap <space>e :exe "!tmux send-keys -t.- 'cd $TEST' Enter"<Cr> :exe "!tmux send-keys -t.- 'source $TEST_NT/bin/activate' Enter"<Cr>
```

how can I break this long line into several short lines so that I can see everything in one screen

Something like the following style:

```
 nnoremap <space>e 
     :exe "!tmux send-keys -t.- 'cd $TEST' Enter"<Cr> 
     :exe "!tmux send-keys -t.- 'source $TEST_NT/bin/activate' Enter"<Cr>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can split your long line by inserting a Vim line continuation character (backslash) at the beginning of each continued line:

```
nnoremap <space>e 
       \ :exe "!tmux send-keys -t.- 'cd $TEST' Enter"<Cr> 
       \ :exe "!tmux send-keys -t.- 'source $TEST_NT/bin/activate' Enter"<Cr>
```

This is explained here: [`:help line-continuation`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#line-continuation).
You should note the comment on leading whitespace, i.e.:

> All leading whitespace characters in the line before a backslash are ignored.
>   **Note** however that trailing whitespace in the line before it cannot be
>   inserted freely; it depends on the position where a command is split up
>   whether additional whitespace is allowed or not.

Comment: You beat me by a couple of seconds. If you add the VimDoc link, then I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg: Hmm, hmm. I am reluctant to add a link to online documentation. If I did that now, I would have to do that forever, and I simply dread the effort. I expect you to answer "fair enough" ;-).

Comment: I saved you the work.

Comment: Fair enough :-).

Comment: I was getting issues with additional wrapped lines beginning with `\ :`. This was fine for the first wrapped line, but for others this meant a space was being added and my cursor would move forwards. I therefore had to have `\:` at the beginning of all but one of the lines, instead.